# print formatted output in bash variables

Tags: bash, echo, tail

I am using a bash script where I must store the last n-2 lines of a file in a variable. 
The command I use for this is

```
last_n2_lines=`tail -n+3 $file`
```

Now whenever i echo the $last_n2_lines variable, I get all the lines of my file in a single line. How can I get the same formatting as I had in my original file. I tried printf but it just prints the first field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "$last_n2_lines"
```

`echo` doesn't *see* the original value in your variant, because it's broken down to `argv` array.

Comment: & to add, it's not echo's fault. It's the way shell expands the variables. with double quotes, echo receives ONE argument, which holds entire data.

Comment: does echo do anything funny when the variable contains a ^L character.

Comment: it does not. When working interactive, bash can do something funny (`^` is somewhat special for history substitution, see `histchars` in `man bash`), but not in a script.

Comment: And if you mean `Control+L` (not separate `^`+`L`), it shouldn't be special, neither for `bash` nor for `echo`.